# How to fix missing method exception in Xamarin.Forms PCL Android mobile app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm getting a `System.MissingMethodException` error after updating Xamarin.Forms package for Android Mobile App.
In `MainActivity.cs` line #22:

```
LoadApplication (new App ());
```

Application Output:

```
[] Missing method Android.Runtime.JNIEnv::StartCreateInstance(Type,string,JValue*) in assembly Mono.Android.dll, referenced in assembly /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/XAMLDataBindings_PCL.Droid/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll
```

I have tried `Clean` & `Rebuild All` as mentioned on the Xamarin forum but still not working. The project works for iOS so not sure why Android project won't run now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem today. I removed all Xamarin.* NuGets from the Android project, re-installed Xamarin.Forms and it fetched the previous versions of Xamarin.Android.* NuGets, which is 21.0.3.0. All is working fine now. I am waiting for a fix.

Comment: Yip I got it working when I downgraded back to Xamarin.Forms 1.3.1.6296 and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 19.1.0 instead of using the latest updates 1.4.2.6355 and 22.1.1 respectfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. Solved it by Upgrading instead of Downgrading which is a bit nicer.

'Xamarin Studio' -> 'Check for Updates'
Answered: "Up to date" 
[image]

But when looking at the Solution tree at the left of the screen under your xxx.Droid project it wrote that the 'Packages' had some updates.
After opening the 'Packages' folder it tells you exactly which package can be updated.
Right click -> Update.
[image]

I updated the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4
It worked.
Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks after updating Xamarin forms it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception just for iOS simulator, cause I use tablet device for Android debugging. Eventually I found it just happened when computer had no Internet access.

So I think the real reason is: **there is an exception caused by network, but Xamarin Studio can't give the real detail, and just can give a stupid fake exception like "System.MissingMethodException: Attempted to access a missing method."**

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the [FloatingActionButton](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FAB.Forms/2.1.1) cause the problems!

```
FAB.Droid.FloatingActionButtonRenderer.InitControl();
```